# Удалить сегмент на Unix

Tags: c, unix

Задание:

> Реализуйте системную функцию, которая позволяла бы пользователю удалять сегмент файла, расположенный между двумя адресами, заданными в виде смещений, и сжимать файл.

В методичке как-то вяло об этом. Можете ткнуть, где почитать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скопируйте "хвост" к началу на величину удаляемого сегмента. Потом урежьте (man 2 ftruncate) файл.

Comment: точно. самый лучший вариант

Comment: спасибо за помощь